# Where to ask about creating a 3D model from a mould?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not sure which Stack Exchange to post this on, so I'm asking for recommendation to a Stack Exchange about 3D printing/3DS Max Models.

My question is, how can you scan in a mould you made at home, so you can create a 3D model from it in software like 3DS Max?

Is there a website that offers laser scanning to a digital model?

I have googled a bunch of things, but because I'm unsure of the correct terminology, I haven't seem to come across anything relevant.

Comment: Engineering Stack Exchange could be helpful, but it's iffy.

Answer (score 4):

Since January 2016, the Stack Exchange network has a [dedicated site for 3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/). They have [some questions about scanning](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scanning), too. Your current question is a bit open-ended, but might work on this specific site; it's listed as one of the Common Topics in their [Help Center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - **Best Practices.** Questions involving the identification or outlining of common procedures.